# Картинка, прикрепляемая к ссылке ВК

Tags: html, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как задать конкретную картинку, которая всегда будет прикрепляться к ссылке, размещенной ВК?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте следующий мета тэг:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Ссылка на иллюстрацию" />
```